# Apache Allow Mentioned Query String ReturnURL

Tags: regex, apache

I've a requirement wherein I wanted to allow only configured return url. Remaining ones should be routed to error message 403.

Currently the apache code i've tried is as shown below.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (returnURL|[&]returnURL)=(http|https)://(my[.]return[.]site[.]com)[&]{0,1}
RewriteRule ^(.*) / [R=403,L]
```

With this when I hit the main url consisting of returnURL as `(returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.return.site.com%2Fmock%2Fdummy-es)` or `(returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com)` they are working. My requirement is the returnURL with google.com should show 403 error.

Can you help me to fix the 403 error ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to achieve my requirement but somehow the source website in whose apache I've configured is not working. I think the below command is showing 403 when there's no query_string returnURL is passed - which shouldn't be the case.
Can you guide me if you are already aware of?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(returnURL|[&]returnURL)=(http|https)(%3A%2F%2F|://)my.return.site.com
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working for me with piece of code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} returnURL [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(returnURL|[&]returnURL)=(http|https)(%3A%2F%2F|://)(my.return.site.com)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```